# Custom CSS not overriding Bootstrap CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Kind of a peculiar thing happening here...

I'm using ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2015. When I add custom CSS within a `<style>` tag in the header of my HMTL document, my CSS will override Bootstrap's CSS, but when I reference my CSS in an external .css file it does not... Here is my code (the CSS in the style tag is the exact same as what's in the external css sheet):

```
<head runat="server">
//BOOTSTRAP CSS
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<%--<link rel="stylesheet" href="App_Code/MainStyleSheet.css" type="text/css" />--%> 
//UNCOMMENTING THIS WILL NOT OVERRIDE BOOTSTRAP CSS

<style>
    //THIS CSS WILL OVERRIDE BOOTSTRAP CSS
    .navbar {
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-size: 12px;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        border-radius: 0px !important;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">X.com</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contract</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
</body>
```

All searches on Google for a resolution say that putting my .css link underneath the Boostrap CSS links should override it, but that's what I've tried and it's not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: ASSUMING that the stylesheet is in the directory you have specificied, then the style declarations in your custom CSS will override any style declarations in the bootstrap based on the code above.  In order to help, we'd need to see a specific example of a given rule that you observe that is not being overridden.

Comment: show your [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @dippas Updated it. Does that help?

Comment: where is your code from CSS file that doesn't apply?

Comment: @dippas It's the exact same code that's within my custom style tag in the header. The navbar will not change when I reference css from the external sheet, but will change if I put it in the style tag. I'm wondering if it's some sort of Visual Studio 2015 setting that needs to be changed or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `MainStyleSheet.css` file outside your `App_Code` folder. `App_Code` folder has a default **Compile** build action instead of **Content**.

Comment: This was the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try and wrapping your html code inside a div and give it a class/id and try to override with that wrapping div.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapping_class">    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapping_class .navbar.navbar-default{
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

This is a solution based on CSS specificity that plays a role in overriding certain CSS rules based on their power.

Refer to this link for table of specificity values (for Star Wars fans a treat):
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/